# My profile icon changed without my doing. How do I get it back?

Tags: support, bug, profile-page

My profile icon changed this morning without my doing.  Is this a known issue on the SE network?  I liked my old blue-colored design.  Is there any way to recover it?

Comment: Related [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283643/why-is-my-profile-image-different).

Answer (score 7):

This has happened elsewhere in the network, I saw it [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9093/my-profile-picture-pattern-just-changed-automatically-how-can-i-restore-the-old) (as well as for [this Physics moderator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/2451/qmechanic)) and there is also [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283643/why-is-my-profile-image-different) on the mother meta. I'm not sure why it happened, or even if it's internal to SE or an issue with Gravatar, but it seems to have affected a lot of people.

The only way I know to get it back is to Google or Bing your username and hope that the old picture is still in a cache somewhere. In your case, the old picture looked like this if I remember correctly:

[image]

You can now just load that directly.

Comment: Thanks!!  You are my hero!  I was so disappointed my icon changed.  I'll add the bugs tag so someone takes a look at it.

Comment: No worries. I think the diamonds are aware of it but it can't hurt to add a voice from the affected.

Comment: Interestingly, for me the StackExchange bar on the top still holds my old avatar, while under my proile I see a new one.

Comment: @IstvánZachar That's absolutely golden. This is probably a heck of a bug for whoever in the SE dev team is looking at it. (Because y'all *are* looking at it, right?)